# Yii framework getting error in configuration

Tags: yii

I am trying to configure my Yii framework and I am stuck in one step. I run command `yiic webapp ..\..\yiitestapp` and "many" of these to start the app but I got a same error every time.

> yii is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program and batch file

I also set my environmental variable as ";D:\xampp\php"

And my Yiiframework location is "D:\Xampp\htdocs\yiiframework\yiiframework"

Can any one guide me for the right solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `yiic webapp ....\yiitestapp` from the `Yii\framework` folder.